# acpi rtc wakeup on battery (Debian testing)

Tags: debian, acpi, hibernate, battery

Setting an rtc alarm via `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` leads to successful resume from hibernate when this Asus laptop is plugged in, but when on battery it stays powered off (but resuming from suspend works fine).

I'm wondering if it's related to this message in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

but extensive googling fails to throw up anything solved (as far as I can see); I've tried adding acpi_osi settings as per [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179530) thread, but to no avail.

kernel is 4.6 series (currently booting a different kernel to test [no difference] but can check if required)

Any ideas?